# Convert Excel to XML with Value Tag

Tags: xml, excel

I have a XML that looks like this.. Need some help convert Excel to XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<Folders>

  <level1 Value="Communications">
     <level2>Correspondence</level2>   
     <level2>Project Meetings</level2>  
  </level1>

  <level1 Value="Project Controls">
     <level2>Close Out</level2>   
     <level2>Financials</level2>  
  </level1>

  <level1 Value="Reports">
     <level2>Close Out</level2>   
     <level2>Financials</level2>  
  </level1>

</Folders>
```

and Excel looks like this.. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFdMi.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this formula starting from cell `C2` and drag it down,

```
=IF(A2<>"","<"&$A$1&" Value="&""""&MID(A2,5,999)&""""&">","      <"&$B$1&">"&MID(B2,5,999)&"</"&$B$1&">")
```

[image]

You could then copy this to a txt file and make small modifications.